# Why this isn't an infinite loop? How is it working?

Tags: c, for-loop, boolean, type-conversion, infinite-loop

Trying this code and the output as per my book is -10 to -1. How this is being printed is really baffling me.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() 
{ 
    int var = -10;
    for(; var; printf("%d\n ", var++));
}
```

Comment: I ran it and it stops as expected when 'var' reaches 0, i.e false

Comment: "Why this isn't an infinite loop?" Why did you expect it to be an infinite loop?

Comment: What did you expect to be printed and why?

Comment: there are only a couple of valid signatures for the `main()` function.  They are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Although Visual Studio will allow invalid signatures, like `void main()`, that does not make it correct. Any other compiler will output warning messages about such invalid `main()` signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step:

The `int var` variable is initialised to `-10`. So far, so good.

Now we get to the interesting part of this: the `for` loop. We have a powerful construct with the following form:

```
for (/* initialisation-statement */ ; /* condition */ ; /* iteration-statement */)
    /* statement or block of code */
```

With your code, we have nothing for the initialisation statement (`int var = -10` could go here), `var` for the condition, and `printf("%d\n ", var++)` for the iteration statement.

In case you're not familiar with how `for` loops, here's a more primitive (but still equivalent) form:

```
{
    /* initialisation-statement */;
startloop:
    if (/* condition */) {
        /* statement or block of code */
        /* iteration-statement */;
        goto startloop;
    }
}
```

Putting `for(int var = -10; var; printf("%d\n ", var++));` into this, we get:

```
{
    int var = -10;
startloop:
    if (var) {
        ;
        printf("%d\n ", var++);
        goto startloop;
    }
}
```

When the `printf("%d\n ", var++);` statement is executed, it prints the value of `var++` to `stdout`. The postfix version of the `++` operator increments the value, but evaluates to the original value.

Because `var` controls the loop, it will keep the loop going as long as it evaluates to `true` (non-zero). Since `var` is incrementing from `-10`, it will end up reaching `0` and ending the loop.

SIDE NOTE: `void main()` is not standard. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is working for below reasons

- The `var` in the if condition serves as a boolean expression, its value is evaluated and any **non-zero** value serves as **true** and a **zero** value serves as **false**.
- `var++` in `printf("%d\n ", var++)` is postfix operator applied on `var`. It takes the current value and then increments `var` by one.
- Eventually `var` reaches zero (Read it along with the first point)

Answer (score 1):

Here you have your code a little bit formatted. Note that the following code does exactly the same thing as yours:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{ 
    int var;

    for (var=-10; var!=0 ;var++) {
        printf("%d\n ", var);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The condition `var!=0` will be evaluated in your code as well automatically. In C everything `!=0` is `true` and `0` is `false`.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP question to why is this an infinite loop. OP is probably confused with what for does and what var++ does.

Comment: @TonyTannous I just thought that he knows what for and ++ means (you can read it up in every beginner tutorial) so I guessed the function was unclear because of the formatting and the automatical `!=0`.

Comment: @TonyTannous The question is why this is _not_ an infinite loop. So this answer is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in programming, every integer (to a boolean) except for a 0 is interpreted as the boolean `true`.
**Only a 0 is interpreted as `false`**, so the loop breaks at `var = 0` and 0 doesn't get printed.
Also: If you would put any positive integer in `var` and run the same loop, the loop would count up infinite times because it never hits 0, except if you'd wait to get to an overflow. That is, when you add 1 to **2,147,483,647** (increment) and get a **-2,147,483,648**. Since then `var` is negative again but still counting up, eventually you reach 0 and the loop will break.

Comment: If you take a positive value for `var` your variable will overflow and therefore hit 0.

Answer (score 0):

first, var++ means var = var + 1;
which means that the loop goes from -10 to -1.
therefore printf("%d\n ", var++) will increment var by one and print the var.
the diff between var++ and ++var is that in var++ the printf happened first and than the +1 because of that you see output from -10 to -1.

second, 0 in C means false. then var become 0 the loop stops.

also the loop can be for(int var = -10;var;printf("%d\n ", var++)) ; which is the same as  for(;var;printf("%d\n ", var++)) ;